# Django Multi table inheritance serializer display

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have extended my model like this.

```
class Item(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Category1(Item):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Category2(Item):
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Order(models.Model):
    # fields

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey("Order", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="order_items")
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Is there any way to access the child fields from the parent model? From the serializer, I have to display all the details from the Order model.
`Order` -> `OrderItem` -> `Item`

I was able to display up to the `Item` details, but I have to display the other fields from  `Category1` and `Category2`. Is there any way I can execute this? My serializer is like this

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = "__all__"

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer will be to use `SerializerMethodField`, this can be one way to do it. It can something like this:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_category1')
    category_2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_category2')

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_category1(self, instance):
        return instance.item.category1.code

    def get_category2(self, instance):
        return instance.item.category2.status
```

But my advise would be simplifying the model design with foreign keys instead of inheritance (Unless this is required for other reasons, then you can ignore the next).

To be like this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Category1(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_cat1')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Category2(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='item_cat2')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item = models.ForeignKey("Item", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then use simple nested serializers